# for loop in mozart/oz doesn't work

Tags: function, for-loop, oz, mozart

I want to have a **for loop** in my program which is written in **mozart-oz**. every time I try a for loop, it gives me error. I've checked the syntax and its true but it gives error. here is my code:

**OZ:**

```
declare
fun {Test L}
   for E in L do
      {Browse L}
   end
end

declare
L = [1 2 3 4 5]
{Test L}
```

please help.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the missing return value of `Test`.
If you want to define a "function" which does not return anything, use the `proc`keyword:

```
declare
proc {Test L}
   for E in L do
      {Browse L}
   end
end

L = [1 2 3 4 5]
{Test L}
```